# How update a view without refresh all view?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

Example: 
Using a ListView, I get 10 items from a database and show on the view. When the user scroll down and click in a button, I wanna bring from database and show 10 more items. However I don't wanna refresh the whole view, just add 10 more.

I was using Cursor and Adapter to ListView, so, when I swap the Cursor with new data, the Adapter fill the ListView refreshing all items.

I'm looking for some tutorial, class or any idea to make that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListView` is an old class added way back at the start in API level 1.
The adapters you use with `ListView` only have `notifyDataSetChanged()` for refreshing the data to be displayed.

Google were aware of this limitation and over a year ago released [`RecyclerView`](http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html), which is a more advanced and flexible replacement for `ListView`.
The [`RecyclerView.Adapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html) class has many more methods such as;
[`notifyItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemRangeInserted(int,%20int))
which is the ideal method for your situation here.

Using the [Support Library `RecyclerView`](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-recyclerview) will give you compatibility right back to API 7 (Android 2.1 Eclair).